# org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property of bean class Bean property is not readable or has an invalid getter method

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Spring MVC is new to me. I would like to have some comprehensive literature with example about Spring MVC(even official docs are not simple to understand).

So the problem that i face is:

```
Jun 15, 2013 2:42:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/controller] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/index.jsp at line 27

24: 
25: <form:form  commandName="creationDate" method="GET" action="add">
26: 
27: <form:label path="creationDate.ParticularDate">Particular Date</form:label>
28: <form:input path="creationDate.ParticularDate" />
29: 
30: <form:label path="creationDate.childGoSchoolDate">Child go to School</form:label>


Stacktrace:] with root cause
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'creationDate' of bean class [edu.demidov.dom.CreationDate]: Bean property 'creationDate' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:707)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getNestedBeanWrapper(BeanWrapperImpl.java:554)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getBeanWrapperForPropertyPath(BeanWrapperImpl.java:531)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:697)
    at org.springframework.validation.AbstractPropertyBindingResult.getActualFieldValue(AbstractPropertyBindingResult.java:99)
    at org.springframework.validation.AbstractBindingResult.getFieldValue(AbstractBindingResult.java:218)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:120)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:179)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.autogenerateFor(LabelTag.java:130)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.resolveFor(LabelTag.java:120)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.writeTagContent(LabelTag.java:90)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:103)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.index_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005flabel_005f0(index_jsp.java:184)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.index_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(index_jsp.java:128)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:88)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:419)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:471)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:329)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:264)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Why does it happen? I don't understand why does it say that I don't have proper setter and getter method for my Entity, and I don't think I have to define them in my controller class. Am I right?

My controller:

```
@Autowired
    private ControllerSupportClass controllerSupportClass; 


        public void setControllerSupportClass(
                ControllerSupportClass controllerSupportClass) {
            this.controllerSupportClass = controllerSupportClass;
        }


        @RequestMapping(value ="/index", method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView firstPage(Model model) {

            CreationDate creationDate = new CreationDate();
            model.addAttribute("creationDate", creationDate);


            return new ModelAndView("index");
        }


        @RequestMapping(value ="/result", method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public String SecondActionPage(@RequestParam String particularDate, 
                                       @RequestParam String nameOfInstitution, 
                                       @RequestParam String typeName, 
                                       Model model) throws Exception {


                if(particularDate !="" && nameOfInstitution !="" && typeName=="") {

                    controllerSupportClass.findWithDateAndName(nameOfInstitution, particularDate, model);

                } else if(particularDate !="" && nameOfInstitution =="" && typeName !="") {

                    controllerSupportClass.findWithAddedDateAndType(typeName, particularDate, model);

                } else if(particularDate !="" && nameOfInstitution =="" && typeName==""){

                    controllerSupportClass.findWithAddedDate(particularDate, model);

                } else if(particularDate !="" && nameOfInstitution !="" && typeName !="") {

                    throw new Exception("Search by choose all parameters is not exceptable");

                } else {

                    throw new Exception("You didn't put any search parameters");

                }


            return "result";

        }

        @RequestMapping(value="/add", method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public String addingData(@ModelAttribute("creationDate") CreationDate creationDate, BindingResult result, Model model) {


            controllerSupportClass.saveDataToDataBase(creationDate);

            return "add";

        }

}
```

And my jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="utf-8"%>

<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>    

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Sorting page</title>
</head>

<body>

<h3>Insert data:</h3>

<form:form  commandName="CreationDate" method="GET" action="add">

<form:label path="creationDate.particularDate">Particular Date</form:label>
<form:input path="creationDate.particularDate" />

<form:label path="creationDate.childGoSchoolDate">Child go to School</form:label>
<form:input path="creationDate.childGoSchoolDate"/>


<form:label path="creationDate.childAdmissionDate">Child admission Date</form:label>
<form:input path="creationDate.childAdmissionDate"/>

<input type="submit" value="Save"/>

</form:form>

</body>

</html>
```

Yeah, my CreationDate Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CREATION_DATE")
@NamedQueries ({
@NamedQuery(name="creationDate.findById", query="select distinct c from CreationDate c left join fetch c.institution n " +
                                                  "left join fetch c.scheduleRotationChild s where c.dateId= :i")
})
public class CreationDate implements Serializable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1648102358397071136L;


    private int dateId;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=IDENTITY)
        @Column(name="DATE_ID")
        public int getDateId() {
            return dateId;
        }

        public void setDateId(int dateId) {
            this.dateId = dateId;
        }


    private Date particularDate;

        @Column(name="PARTICULAR_DATE")
        public Date getParticularDate() {
            return particularDate;
        }

        public void setParticularDate(Date particularDate) {
            this.particularDate = particularDate;
        }


    private int version;

        @Version
        @Column(name="VERSION")
        public int getVersion() {
            return version;
        }

        public void setVersion(int version) {
            this.version = version;
        }


    private Date childGoSchoolDate;

        @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
        @Column(name="CHILD_GO_SCHOOL_DATE")
        public Date getChildGoSchoolDate() {
            return childGoSchoolDate;
        }

        public void setChildGoSchoolDate(Date childGoSchoolDate) {
            this.childGoSchoolDate = childGoSchoolDate;
        }


    private Date childAdmissionDate;

        @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
        @Column(name="CHILD_ADMISSION_DATE")
        public Date getChildAdmissionDate() {
            return childAdmissionDate;
        }

        public void setChildAdmissionDate(Date childAdmissionDate) {
            this.childAdmissionDate = childAdmissionDate;
        }


    private Set<Institution> institution = new HashSet<Institution>();

        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinTable(name="CREATIONDATE_INSTITUTION", 
                                    joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="DATE_ID"), 
                                    inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="INSTITUTION_ID"))
        public Set<Institution> getInstitution() {
            return institution;
        }

        public void setInstitution(Set<Institution> institutionSet) {
            this.institution = institutionSet;
        }


    private List<ScheduleRotationChild> scheduleRotationChild = new ArrayList<ScheduleRotationChild>();

        @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval=true)
        @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinTable(name="SRC_DATE", 
                                    joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="DATE_ID"),
                                    inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="SRC_ID"))
        public List<ScheduleRotationChild> getScheduleRotationChild() {
            return scheduleRotationChild;
        }

        public void setScheduleRotationChild(
                List<ScheduleRotationChild> scheduleRotationChild) {
            this.scheduleRotationChild = scheduleRotationChild;
        }





        public void addSetInstitutions(Set<Institution> institution) {

            setInstitution(institution);

        }


        public void addSRC(List<ScheduleRotationChild> srcinstitution) {

        setScheduleRotationChild(srcinstitution);

        }



        public String toString() {

            return "\n" + "ID: " + dateId + " \n " 
            + "Дата: " +particularDate + " \n " 
            + "Дети идут в школу, год: " + childGoSchoolDate + " \n " 
            + "Дата приема детей: " + childAdmissionDate + "  " + scheduleRotationChild + " \n " ;

        }


}
```

I hope this clarifies my problem to you guys. Thank you.

Comment: What does the edu.demidov.dom.CreationDate class look like?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `path` values in your `form:label` and `form:input` tags should be relative to the command object referenced in `form:form`. In other words, the `path` values should be property names of the class of the `creationDate` object. Bascially just remove the `creationDate.` prefix so you end up with this:

```
<form:form  commandName="creationDate" method="GET" action="add">

<form:label path="particularDate">Particular Date</form:label>
<form:input path="particularDate" />

<form:label path="childGoSchoolDate">Child go to School</form:label>
```

Assuming that the `creationDate` class has properties (with getters/setters) called `particularDate` and `childGoSchoolDate`.

Comment: You are genius!!! My bow to you. You solved two problems by one answer wich I was faced for whole day today and got so upset... Thank you Thank you Thank you Thank you so much. Chears.

Answer (score 1):

Within the `path` attribute `creationDate.ParticularDate` should probably be `creationDate.particularDate`.

Make sure your `CreationDate` object has a proper property getter method `#getParticularDate()`.

Comment: Yeah. Thank you so much for help I should put it as creationDate.ParticularDate because my get...() method has looks like this: getParticularDate() the problem is solved, but had different one, not for this topic, but realy appreciate to have your help: Error Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'CreationDate' available as request attribute

Comment: You are not passing the `creationDate` as your model attribute in the controler... Btw. you should check superEb's answer as well. He is correct, that the `creationDate.` should not be in the path if that is your command  object.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but the problem is I did not generate the getters and setters, I wrote them down manually. All my paths and methods were correct. So I removed the getter and setter method that I wrote manually and generated them using eclipse. I don't understand the logic behind it but that resolves my issue.

Answer (score 0):

`Command` class is missed with the variable of path mentioned in the form tag.

Answer (score 0):

For beans it's important to provide a getter with a proper name. Say, if some class treats your class as a bean and wants to access property boxType, it's a must to provide a getter getBoxType() with no args. There is a contract for the name of the getter. "get" + capital letter (B) + the rest of the property name.  You may have a public property boxType, but in terms of beans it's uselesess. You need to return value from this field in the getter.
Autogenerated getters are usially OK, but for boolean value some IDE add "is" instead of "get".